# Can SharePoint 2016 site can be edited in SharePoint designer 2013 32 bit?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016

Is SharePoint 2016 site compatible with SharePoint designer 32 bit ? I have a standalone server for share point 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should support because according to MSIgnite announcement, there won't be SPD 2016 and SPD 2013 is last version in this product family.

Some comments from blog.

---

In SharePoint 2016, there will be No More SharePoint Designer, means no new version of SharePoint designer is coming to for new version of SharePoint but we can still use SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint Server 2016.SharePoint Server 2016 is built on the same code base as SharePoint 2013 and the fact that you still can use SharePoint Designer 2013 on SharePoint Online, there are reasons to believe that SharePoint Designer 2013 will function very well with SharePoint Server 2016. There may be features that can’t be used, but you have other tools available such as Visual Studio, PowerShell, Browser and Design Manager

---

Reference link -
http://mstechtalk.com/no-more-sharepoint-designer-and-no-more-sharepoint-foundation-in-sharepoint-2016/

https://www.quora.com/Whats-happening-to-SharePoint-Designer-in-SharePoint-2016-is-it-dead

Answer (score 2):

As we know Microsoft hasn’t announced a frank replacement for SharePoint Designer 2016 yet. meanwhile, you can still use `SharePoint Designer 2013 64 bit` as well as InfoPath 2013 for use with SharePoint 2016.

For more details check [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What’s the alternatives ?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

Regarding `Is SharePoint 2016 supports SharePoint designer 2013 32 bit or 64 bit` ?

Yes, it supports 32-bit / 64-bit , but it's heavily recommended to install 64-bit for future compatibility. for more details [check Choose the 64-bit or 32-bit version of Office 2016](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Choose-the-64-bit-or-32-bit-version-of-Office-2016-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261)